# Dropdown Menu Jquery html

Tags: jquery, html

```
<nav>
            <ul class="huvud" id="top">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Godis</a>
                    <ul class="hand">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Choklad</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="HTML/lakrits.html">Lakrits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Bakelser</a>
                    <ul class="hand">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Croissant</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">idk</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Drycker</a> 
                    <ul class="hand">
                        <li><a href="#">Läsk</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Energidryck</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('nav').hover(
   ()=>$('.hand',this).slideDown(700)
,
   ()=> $('.hand', this).slideUp(700)
)
});
  </script>
```

I've made this code and what this does is that when I hover above something in the Nav it makes so that all the extra lists show up, that wasn't the intention of this code, what I wanted to do was that if I hovered over "#Godis" then only that one would extend and not the others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the correct submenu relevant to the main menu item to open/close.

```js
//$('ul.hand').hide();// Uncomment tis if you want all of them to be hidden initially.
$('ul.huvud > li').hover(function () {
  $('> ul.hand',this).slideDown(700);
},function () {
  $('> ul.hand',this).slideUp(700);
});
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="huvud" id="top">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="main">Godis</a>
            <ul class="hand">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Choklad</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="HTML/lakrits.html">Lakrits</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="main">Bakelser</a>
            <ul class="hand">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Croissant</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">idk</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="main">Drycker</a> 
            <ul class="hand">
                <li><a href="#">Läsk</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Energidryck</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, as i understand this would be your perfect answer:

```html
<nav>
            <ul class="huvud" id="top">
                <li>
                    <a id="godis" href="#">Godis</a>
                    <ul class="hand1">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Choklad</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="HTML/lakrits.html">Lakrits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="Bakelser" href="#">Bakelser</a>
                    <ul class="hand2">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Croissant</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">idk</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="Drycker" href="#">Drycker</a>
                    <ul class="hand3">
                        <li><a href="#">Läsk</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Energidryck</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.hand1',this).hide();
$('.hand2',this).hide();
$('.hand3',this).hide();
$('#godis').hover(
   ()=>$('.hand1',this).slideDown(500)
,
   ()=> $('.hand1', this).slideUp(500)
);
$('#Bakelser').hover(
   ()=>$('.hand2',this).slideDown(500)
,
   ()=> $('.hand2', this).slideUp(500)
)
$('#Drycker').hover(
   ()=>$('.hand3',this).slideDown(500)
,
   ()=> $('.hand3', this).slideUp(500)
)
});
  </script>
```

Comment: it works, but only the ".hand1" extends, and that isn't really functional with what I'm trying to do

Comment: ".hand1" is only working because in <script> code i did added that section only, If you do same for other section then that will work too.    And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what im trying to do is a menu that extends when hovering over, if you  run the code snippet you made it should look something like that but on 1, 2, and 3. edit: fixed it

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand well your question, but you can try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nav").hover(
    function() {
        $('<id/div_here_you_point>').stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
    },
    function() {
        $('<id/div_here_you_point>').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');
    }
});
});
```